# Checking to see if a list is ordered consecutively

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is there any library function in Haskell that'll allow me to check if a list is ordered consecutively? eg. [1,2,3,4] is valid, [1,2,3,10] is invalid.

Basically I can have a list that ranges anywhere between 3 to 5 elements and I'm trying to check if that list is ordered consecutively.

My Attempt (I'm not sure if this is the right way to approach it, seems to be way too much repetition)

```
isSucc:: [Integer] -> Bool
isSucc[]            = True
isSucc(x:y:zs)      = 
    if (x+1) == y
    then True && isSucc(y:zs)
    else isSucc(y:zs)
```

After I have this function working, I'm planning on using it to filter a lists of lists (Keep the list inside the list only and only if it is ordered consecutively)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no standard function for that.

Here's a fixed version of your function, making it generic, removing the redundant conditions and adding the missing ones:

```
isSucc :: (Enum a, Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isSucc [] = True
isSucc (x:[]) = True
isSucc (x:y:zs) | y == succ x = isSucc $ y:zs
isSucc _ = False
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the trick `zipWith f xs (drop 1 xs)` to apply `f` to consecutive pairs of list elements. (Notice `drop 1` rather than `tail`, because the latter fails if the list is empty!)

If you replace `f` with `<=` you'll get a list of `Bool` values. Now see whether they're all `True`.

```
isSucc xs = and $ zipWith (<=) xs (drop 1 xs)
```

Comment: Way to misunderstand the question! It should be clear how to change `f` to make this do what you want, however.

Comment: I've never thought of doing a drop 1 instead. Seems like a better solution to implement but would `drop 1 xs` be more expensive compared to `(x:xs)`?

Comment: Actually, `tail` is fine when used with `zipWith` in this case, as an accident of the order `zipWith` evaluates its arguments in. But it's not an accident that it evaluates its arguments in that order.

Comment: Just for the record, in order to match the question, that would be `and $ zipWith ((==) . succ) xs (tail xs)`.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use a little more readable solution than one that has been offered by [MathematicalOrchid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1006010/mathematicalorchid).

First of all we will define the utilitarian function *pairwise* that might be useful in many different circumstances:

```
pairwise xs = zip xs $ tail xs
```

or in more modern way:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<*>))

pairwise = zip <*> tail
```

and then use it with the other combinators:

```
isSucc xs = all (\(x,y) -> succ x == y) $ pairwise xs
```

Comment: This solution doesn't do what the OP wants, and is wrong in the same manner as the one by @MatemachicalOrchid. See my comment to his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542328/checking-to-see-if-a-list-is-ordered-successively/15542475#comment22025580_15542475

Comment: I love how you used a function's instance of Applicative to compose with `<*>`. Still trying to wrap my head around it ) Mindbending stuff!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way,

```
isOrdered :: (Enum a, Eq a) => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
isOrdered op (a:b:ls) = op a b && isOrdered op (b:ls)
isOrdered op _ = True
```

Thus,

```
isSucc = isOrdered ((==) . succ)
```

Comment: This is incorrect -- the OP wants to check that elements are consecutive, not just that they are ordered. You can correct this with `isSucc = isOrdered ((==) . succ)`

Comment: I'm so glad to see that _every single poster_ misread the question in the same way as me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that all consecutive differences are equal to one, you can use

isIncreasingByOne :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> Bool
   isIncreasingByOne = all (==1) (zipWith (-) (tail xs) xs)

This works for numeric types (hence the `Num a` constraint), including `Float` and `Double`. It's also easy to adapt if you want to check that a sequence is increasing by more than 5 at a time, say.

Answer (score 0):

-- This checks if ordered

```
isordd:: [Int] -> Bool 
isordd [] = True
isordd (x:y:xs) 
 | x > y = False
 | lengh xs == 0 = True
 | otherwise = isordd (y:xs)
```

-- This calculates the length of the list

```
lengh::[Int]->Int
lengh [] = 0
lengh (x:xs) = 1+lengh xs
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using list comprehension, would be:

```hs
pairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairs xs = zip xs (tail xs)

isSucc :: (Enum a, Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
isSucc xs = and [y == succ x || x == succ y | (x,y) <- pairs xs]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, there is a library function that does that:**

**Data.List.Predicate.ascSequential.**

First, my solution:

```
consecutive :: (Eq a, Enum a) => [a] -> Bool
consecutive [] = True
consecutive (x:xs) = and (zipWith (==) (x:xs) [x..])
```

Here we leverage a builtin function of the `Enum` type class, `enumFrom`, in the syntax sugar `[x..]` to create the correct consecutive sequence.  Then we can compare each item in the given list which the expected enumeration using `zipWith (==)`.  The function `and` will bail when we encounter the first item in the given list than does not equal the expected enumeration.

This works for common types like `Int` and `Char`, but the library function `ascSequential` is more complete.

```
-- From: Data.List.Predicate                                                
ascSequential :: (Enum a) => [a] -> Bool                                    
ascSequential []  = True                                                                            
ascSequential [_] = True 
ascSequential xs  = and $ zipWith (==) xs' [head xs' ..]
  where
    xs' = map fromEnum xs
```

This function maps the given list and expected enumeration to lists of `Int` before comparing them, using `fromEnum :: (Enum a) => a -> Int`.  This is otherwise the same as my version, but it also works for the corner case of `[()]` *(which I do not understand anyway)*.

```
import Test.QuickCheck

prop0 :: [Int] -> Property
prop0 xs = property (consecutive xs == ascSequential xs)

prop1 :: [Char] -> Property
prop1 xs = property (consecutive xs == ascSequential xs)

prop2 :: (Eq a, Enum a) => [a] -> Property
prop2 xs = property (consecutive xs == ascSequential xs)
```

```
*Main> quickCheck prop0
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
*Main> quickCheck prop1
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
*Main> quickCheck prop2
*** Failed! Falsified (after 4 tests and 1 shrink):     
[(),()]
```