# Test if a list is sorted

Tags: haskell

It is really easy to find a minimum of a list in haskell:

`foldl1 (min) [9,5,7,3,7,4,6,10]` gives me `3`. ;)

I replaced `min` with `<=` to test if a list is sorted:

`foldl1 (<=) [9,5,7,3,7,4,6,10]`

I get this error message:

```
No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal `9'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Bool)
In the expression: 9
In the second argument of `foldl1', namely `[9, 5, 7, 3, ....]'
In the expression: foldl1 (<=) [9, 5, 7, 3, ....]
```

Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542328/checking-to-see-if-a-list-is-ordered-consecutively

Comment: `and [x <= y | (x:y:_) <- tails list]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foldl1` has the following type:

```
foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

However, `(<=)` has type `a -> a -> Bool`, which, unless `a` isn't `Bool`, doesn't work for `foldl1`. So you cannot use `foldl1` in this way. A possible solution would be

```
isSorted :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
isSorted []       = True
isSorted [x]      = True
isSorted (x:y:xs) = x <= y && isSorted (y:xs)
```

However, you can also zip every element with its successor, and then check whether `x <= y` holds:

```
isSorted' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
isSorted' xs = all id . map (\(x,y) -> x <= y) . zip xs $ tail xs
```

Comment: `all id` could just be `and`

Comment: @jozefg: And the lambda should be `uncurry (<=)`, thanks. I need to get a little bit better with Applicative, I always forget those constructions.

Comment: @jozefg: Or remove the `map` and just do `all (uncurry (<=)) ...`

Answer (score 6):

Yes. To start with our base case

```
isSorted [] = True -- An empty list is sorted
```

Now for the non empty case

```
isSorted (x:xs) = fst $ foldl' step (True, x) xs
  where step (b, x) y = (b && (x <= y), y)
```

Essentially we're keeping track of the sorted state in the first argument of the tuple and the previous element in the second, we then update the sorted state and the value each step.

Though this isn't lazy and doesn't work on infinite lists, instead a try

```
 import Control.Applicative

allSorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
allSorted = all (uncurry (<=)) . (zip <$> id <*> tail)
allSorted = all (uncurry (<=)) . (zip <*> tail)
allSorted = and . (zipWith (<=) <*> tail)
```

Comment: `isSorted = and . (zipWith (<=) <*> tail)` would be prettier here, I think (since we carried the slimming this far).

Comment: Or you're right, that is pretty @AndrásKovács updated

Comment: but sorted can mean both non-decreasing and non-increasing too. I wonder, can it be detected in one pass?

Comment: [yes, it can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22050710/test-if-a-list-is-sorted/22053358?noredirect=1#comment33442005_22053358).

Comment: You should include `allSorted xs = and $ zipWith (<=) xs (tail xs)` and `allSorted xs = all (uncurry (<=)) $ zip xs (tail xs)` as well.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for both ascending and descending order

```
sorted a = same $ map (>0) $ filter (/=0) $ zipWith (-) a (tail a)
 where
   same (x:xs) = and $ map (==x) xs
```

test cases

```
> sorted [1..10]
True
> sorted [10,9..1]
True
> sorted [1,4,3]
False
> sorted [71,3,3,2]
True
> sorted [1,1,3]
True
```

Comment: the OP seems to consider non-decreasing or non-increasing lists as sorted, too.

Comment: what about `[1,1,3]`?

Comment: Adapted to other types: `sorted a = same $ filter (/=EQ) $ zipWith compare a (tail a) where same xs = all (==head xs) xs`

Comment: nice idea, to filter-out the EQs.  `same = null . drop 1 . nub` is better, will work for `[1,1,1]` too. : ) then, `sorted = same . filter (/=EQ) . (zipWith compare <*> tail)`.

Comment: Actually, `same xs = all (==head xs) xs` works for empty `xs` too, since `all _|_ [] = True`. This makes `sorted` work for `[1,1,1]`. That being said, your pointfree version is more elegant (albeit a bit golf-y :))

Comment: @WillNess **Never use `nub`.** It is O(n²).

Comment: @nh2 `nub` is O(1) by itself actually. It takes approximately 0 CPU ticks to perform. It's how it is used that says us anything about the overall performance. `print . length . nub` is indeed O(n^2) *worst-case* (ie when all elements are different), still O(n) best-case (when all are the same). `null.drop1.nub` is *always* O(k), *k* being the number of equal elements at the prefix of the input list; it bails out early because of `null.drop 1` and has only *one*  element to compare each incoming element with -- the *first* element.

Comment: @WillNess What you say is right, in this specific application of implementing `same` the bad behaviour of `nub` does not surface. Nevertheless you should never use `nub`, already to reduce its occurrence in any code, so that people don't get use to seeing it, as that has led to the current situation of people thinking "`nub` is the right tool to remove duplicates, right?", and thus O(n²) behaviour appering in many haskell libraries, including fundamental ones written by experts, like `Cabal`.

Answer (score 2):

This was an interesting problem. As mentioned, the types don't match initially, but I decided to give it a go.

I started with zipping:

```
sorted  xs = foldr (&&) True (map (\(a,b) -> a<=b) (zip xs (tail xs)))
```

I didnt like it so I tried using tuples:

```
sorted2 xs = (\(x,y) -> y) (foldl (\(x,y) a -> (a,x<=a && y)) (head xs, True) xs)
```

I wasn't happy with this as the function didn't start with a fold. I tried going back to zipping, this time I defined the zip with folds:

```
zip1 = foldr (\ a f bs -> if null bs then [] else (a,(head bs)):(f (tail bs))) (const [])
```

This gave me an idea. As you can see, the accumulator is a function, and the fold returns a function. We can thus do the same with the sorted function:

```
sorted3 [] = True
sorted3 xs = foldr (\a f b -> (a >= b) && f a) (const True) (tail xs) (head xs)
```

And with that I was happy.
Edit: added empty list check for sorted3 I forgot to add.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my solutions, they borrow ideas from previous answers:

```hs
isSorted xs = and $ zipWith (<=) xs (tail xs)

isSorted xs = all (<=0) $ zipWith (-) xs (tail xs)
```